# C#, CF Listview, Create a View that Just Have ListViewItem text

Tags: c#, listview, view, compact-framework

I am using a Listview in Compact Framework to make a Menu. Listview has 4 views that i can use. LargeIcon,SmallIcon,List,Detail. All of these have the icon image above or next to the Listview item text. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

I want to create another view that is just the Text - more like Detail view but without the Icon on the left side. Is there a way to do this without going as far as making my own onPaint handler?

While using Detail view, I have tried to Null my SmallImageList and LargeImageList and that still leaves empty place holder for the image.

The detail view uses the SmallImageList icons; right now my best solution is to set the listview SmallImageList ImageSize to (1,1) - Which shows a 1 by 1 square image to the left of the Text. As long as the listview background is white AND i Null the image list this works fine. but that means i have to load the images again if user wants to do another view - which i bad performance on Compact Device.

Here is my code for changing the view.

```
private void textView__Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            listView1.View = View.Details;
            listView1.SmallImageList.ImageSize = new Size(1, 1);
        }
```

On the image SmallImageLIst is not Null-ed. And thats what i see with above code. Any Idea??
[image]

Edit : the happens when i null the image lists.

[image]

Comment: also notice the vertical line on left end of the selected item. As long as the icon is there i dont see how that can be removed.

Comment: If you do not want the icon to show, why aren't you using a List control?  Or a grid control?

Comment: Because i want to have the option for the other views! Not all Compact devices have same power...a list is faster to render without image compared to a list that has to create image on each list refresh.

Comment: So you *are* using the icons for the other views?

Comment: yes i am @tcarvin. Remember this is another view. The others should work as designed.

Answer (score 1):

When your [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.view%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is in `Details` mode, set the ImageList properties to NULL (Nothing in VB).

When you change back to another view, set the Image List properties back.

[image: ImageList]

**UPDATE**

Click the columns field. See if you have an Image column. If so, delete it or set it's width to 0.

[image: ColumnField]

Sorry, but I don't have a WM6.5 to demo for you. All I have is WM5.0.

Comment: Updated the question with what i see when i null the image lists. I tried to make listView1.LargeImageList.ImageSize value to Size.Empty...that was invalid value error.

Comment: Check your Columns (see UPDATE).

Comment: I'm not adding columns from designer - everything is done by Code. And I only have one column - no header. I just commented out the imageList assignments and image size assignments and got what i wanted - just list no icon. I think the problem is _there is no way to zero the image sizes_ once they are initialized - the best we can do is 1x1 size or Not Initialize it at all.

Comment: That's what I said in the first line: Set the ImageSize properties to NULL (or Nothing in VB).

Comment: if you try to set ImageSize to Null you get 
**Cannot convert null to 'System.Drawing.Size' because it is a non-nullable value type** and this is after nulling the Large and small ImageLists. 

I feel like deleting the handle for the ImageLists solves the problem but i dont know how to do that. Once a LV is 'related' to large,small ImageLists there is no way to remove the 'connection' - its always going to save space for them in diff views. So far the only solution is creating new Listview and not init the ImageLists.

Comment: Just write `listView1.SmallImageList = null;` and you're done.